# Can't make camera wireframe visible

Tags: 3d-view, camera, visibility

It was visible before, but now I can't really get it to come back.

The only way I found was to go through viewport overlays and tick extras, but I don't want it to look like this:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to see:

[image]

Comment: What is "make camera wireframe visible"? Can you describe it more? Also if you can attach some screen with desired result (found across a n internet? ...

Comment: As in the object the represents the camera itself. I was visible before and now I'm trying to get it back. Image in main post. @vklidu

Comment: You cant display Camera with Extras disabled ... if you don't want to see light objects you can filter visibility by "Object Type" (icon most at left on right side of viewport - cursor+eye).